# Java - convert MGRS coordinate to LatLon WGS

Tags: java, android, coordinate-transformation

For my App I need compact code for converting between LatLon (WGS84) and MGRS.

**JCoord.jar:**
Looks great, but the version 1.1 jar is 0.5Mb in size. That is doubles my App for only perfoming a 2-way conversion of coordinates.

**Openmap:** 
Isolating just the MGRSPoint.java (https://code.google.com/p/openmap/source/browse/src/openmap/com/bbn/openmap/proj/coords/MGRSPoint.java) from the rest is not easy.

**GeographicLib:**
This seems a good solution, but I could not find a Java source file. 
Is it available for usage?

**Nasa:** 
The Nasa code looks great, see http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/geom/coords/MGRSCoordConverter.java. Isolating just the MGRS conversion code was not easy.

**GDAL:** 
Was implemented in another programming language.

**IBM (via j-coordconvert.zip):** 
Is complact, suits well for the UTM conversion, but the MGRS conversion is described to be errorneous. Alas.

Is there a good (compact) Java source for converting between LatLon/wgs84 and MGRS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found a sufficient good answer. Berico, thank you!

https://github.com/Berico-Technologies/Geo-Coordinate-Conversion-Java

This source code isolates the NASA Java source code and adds 1 nice utility class.

Examples:

```
double lat = 52.202050;  
double lon = 6.102050;
System.out.println( "To MGRS is " + Coordinates.mgrsFromLatLon( lat, lon));
```

And the other way around:

```
String mgrs = "31UCU 59248 14149"; 
double[] latlon = Coordinates.latLonFromMgrs( mgrs);
```